# Why does the Maven assembly plugin append the descriptor ref to the finalName value?

Tags: java, maven-3

This is plugin configuration I am using:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.changepasswd</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>changepasswd</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn clean install assembly:single` what I get is changepasswd-jar-with-dependencies.jar. How do I tell the assembly plugin to just name it `changepasswd.jar`? Or is that something which is handled outside of the assembly plugin?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482839/maven-assembly-plugin-how-to-use-appendassemblyid/38484021

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your `configuration` element, try adding `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>`. I believe this did the trick for me.